# AWS Codebuild - Error while executing command: python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip. Reason: exit status 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to run a build after creating a stack in the AWS cloudFormation but unfortunately, the build has failed with an error message:

> Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error
> while executing command: python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip.
> Reason: exit status 1

here is the log for the build and why it failed:

```
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:39 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:40 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:41 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:41 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src061758247/src
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:41 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src061758247/src/buildspec.yml
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:41 Processing environment variables
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:41 Decrypting parameter store environment variables
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:41 [WARN] Skipping install of runtimes. Runtime version selection is not supported by this build image.
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src061758247/src
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43 Registering with agent
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43 Phases found in YAML: 4
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43  POST_BUILD: 10 commands
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43  INSTALL: 10 commands
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43  PRE_BUILD: 6 commands
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43  BUILD: 1 commands
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43 Running command echo 'about to call dockerd'
about to call dockerd

[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43 Running command nohup /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 --storage-driver=overlay2&

[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43 Running command timeout 15 sh -c "until docker info; do echo .; sleep 1; done"
Error starting daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 17.09.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
runc version: 3f2f8b84a77f73d38244dd690525642a72156c64
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.14.243-185.433.amzn2.x86_64
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (containerized)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.645GiB
Name: 9d1ea8d456c4
ID: GA3S:TOF2:A43S:WTEP:JIFT:RNGG:X3XM:5N6S:7JMU:5IE3:HV2Z:AFGS
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled

[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:43 Running command curl -sS -o aws-iam-authenticator https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.10.3/2018-07-26/bin/linux/amd64/aws-iam-authenticator

[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:44 Running command curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 44.7M  100 44.7M    0     0  60.0M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 60.1M

[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:45 Running command chmod +x ./kubectl ./aws-iam-authenticator

[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:45 Running command echo `kubectl version`
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 1: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: kubectl: not found


[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:45 Running command export PATH=$PWD/:$PATH

[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:45 Running command python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
Collecting pip
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:339: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning

[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:45 Command did not exit successfully python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip exit status 1
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:45 Phase complete: INSTALL State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/10/15 13:01:45 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip. Reason: exit status 1
```

My buildspec.yaml file looks like this:

```
---
version: 0.2


phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - curl -sS -o aws-iam-authenticator https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.14.6/2019-08-22/bin/linux/amd64/aws-iam-authenticator
      - curl -sS -o kubectl https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.14.6/2019-08-22/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
      - chmod +x ./kubectl ./aws-iam-authenticator
      - export PATH=$PWD/:$PATH
      - apt-get update && apt-get -y install jq python3-pip python3-dev && pip3 install --upgrade awscli
  pre_build:
      commands:
        - TAG="$REPOSITORY_NAME.$REPOSITORY_BRANCH.$ENVIRONMENT_NAME.$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H.%M.%S).$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | head -c 8)"
        - sed -i 's@CONTAINER_IMAGE@'"$REPOSITORY_URI:$TAG"'@' simple_jwt_api.yml
        - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)
        - export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
        - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
        - pytest
  build:
    commands:
      - docker build --tag $REPOSITORY_URI:$TAG .

  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$TAG
      - CREDENTIALS=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn $EKS_KUBECTL_ROLE_ARN --role-session-name codebuild-kubectl --duration-seconds 900)
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')"
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')"
      - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken')"
      - export AWS_EXPIRATION=$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.Expiration')
      - aws eks update-kubeconfig --name $EKS_CLUSTER_NAME
      - kubectl apply -f simple_jwt_api.yml
      - printf '[{"name":"simple_jwt_api","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$TAG > build.json
      - pwd
      - ls
artifacts:
  files: build.json

env:
  parameter-store:
    JWT_SECRET: JWT_SECRET
```

can anyone help me with this issue or guide me to a similar asked question?
thanks

Comment: You haven't provided essential info. What CB image are you using?

Comment: Also you have problem with the installation of kubectl, check that in your output you have `kubectl: not found`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information about your Cloud Build resources and the log output doesn't exactly match the commands in your buildspec.yaml.

However the error you have is because you are trying to run python 2.7 version to upgrade pip. You should use python3 instead.